# How do you set a variable defined as the base class type to a derived type instance in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Java, I can declare a variable as the base class type, and set it to a derived type instance:

```
public class MyClass {
    Base foo;

    public void method(){
        foo = new Derived()
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Base
class Derived extends Base

class MyClass {

  var foo: Base = _ // careful, this is null until it's initialized

  def method() = {
    foo = new Derived
  }

}
```

Comment: @jeffwun: if this answer is not only "helpful" but also "useful" and maybe "answers your question" you should consider using Stackexchange's capabilities to express just that.